# ADF Faces 11g ignores the template when it navigates to the same page

Tags: java, jsf, weblogic-10.x, oracle-adf

I'm using ADF Faces 11g\JDeveloper 11g to develop a web application and using Weblogic 10.3 to deploy it.

I'm having some issues when I navigate to the same JSP page.

Example:

I have a page using a template:

```
    <f:view>
        <af:document id="d1">
            <af:form id="f1">
                <af:pageTemplate viewId="/base/templase.jspx" id="pt1">
                      <f:facet name="body"> 
                          (...)
                               <af:commandButton   action="#{listPersons.query}"
                                                      text="Search"
                                                      id="buttonSeachPersons"/>
(...)
```

and the query method in the backing bean:

```
public void query() {
   this.persons = findPersons(filter);
}
```

It redirects to the same page, but does not includes the template page content.

I tried to return String in the query method and create a navigation, but it did not worked...

Anyone has any tip?

It works fine when it navigates to different pages.

Comment: Can't think why this wouldn't work. So it returns the results of the query but not your styling, other text, etc.? 

Maybe you are taking an exception that is getting swallowed. Try debugging with uncaught exceptions breakpoints enabled. 

Where were the navigation rules defined? (faces-config or adfc-config)

Answer (score 0):

I once had similar problems when redirecting back to the same page. In my case the page reload was not occurring because (I assume) the ADF request processor was doing some 'optimization' and deciding that since the the same page was required, that a reload wasn't needed. I tried everything I could think of to try and force a page refresh but nothing worked.

In the end, I solved my problem by moving the navigation rules from the adfc-config.xml into the faces-config.xml. Since the navigation rules were then plain old JSF rules (rather than ADF rules), there was no optimization, and the navigation was then more consistent.